# Continuity of an integral of characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu,\phi)$ be a topological dynamical system, where $X$ be the circle represented as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{A}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra subsets of $X$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure and $\phi\colon X\rightarrow X$, where
$$\phi(x)=x+a$$
for an arbitrary $a$.

I wish to know how to prove that the function
$$g(y)=\int_{A}\chi_{A}(x+y)\,d\mu(x)$$
is continuous, where $A\subset X$ and $\chi_{A}$ is the characteriscti function of $A$.

My approach to the problem so far:
I tried to deal with the classical definition of continuity, considering $y,y_0$ with close distance and tried to estimate the quantity
$$\left|\int_{A}\chi_{A}(x+y)\,d\mu(x)-\int_{A}\chi_{A}(x+y_0)\,d\mu(x)\right|=\left|\mu(A\cap(A-y))-\mu(A\cap(A-y_0))\right|.$$

I cannot proceed from this point to see how this quantity is small, based on the distance of $y,y_0$.
I am gratefull for any help you give me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about the equality you wrote. The integral $\int_{A}\chi_{A}(x+y)\,d\mu(x)$ should be equal to $\mu(A-y)$. It should be that the difference of the integrals is then the measure of the symmetric difference $(A-y)\Delta (A-y_0)$.

Comment: It might be good to add more context regarding the connection with dynamical systems; currently it seems the problem is purely about integration.